# Jquery Modal Popup not functioning in IE

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

Here is the jquery-ui modal code I have been using:

```
//jQuery form dialog modal popup and submit
$(function() {
$("#facilitiesForm").validate();

$("#facilityForm").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 470,
    width: 650,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
       "Send To The Facilities Manager": function() {
            $("#facilitiesForm").submit();
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
    },
    close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
});

$("#helpForm").validate();

$("#helpdeskForm").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 570,
    width: 650,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
       "Send To The Helpdesk": function() {
            $("#helpForm").submit();
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
    },
    close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
});

$("#adminForm").validate();

$("#adminTasksForm").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 470,
    width: 650,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
       "Send To The Admin": function() {
            $("#adminForm").submit();
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
    },
    close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
});

$("#contactFacilityManager")
    //.button()
    .click(function() {
        $( "#facilityForm" ).dialog( "open" );
    });

$("#contactHelpdesk")
    //.button()
    .click(function() {
        $( "#helpdeskForm" ).dialog( "open" );
    });

$("#contactAdminTasks")
    //.button()
    .click(function() {
        $( "#adminTasksForm" ).dialog( "open" );
    });

});
```

I just started noticing a bug and the popup box will not work in IE. The error I get is:

```
Webpage error details

Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 16
Char: 6
Code: 0
URI: http://newintranet/js/script.js
```

Any ideas why this won't work on IE (works fine on Chrome and FF)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in IE it is throwing syntax error here in the below code. Remove the extra comma it will work fine.

```
buttons: {
       "Send To The Helpdesk": function() {
            $("#helpForm").submit();
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }, //extra comma here
    }
```

Comment: To clarify : only IE minds the trailing commas. Other browsers don't care.

Comment: Yeah, noticed a few minutes after I posted. Thanks for the find... there were a few more down the page as well... could have sworn I copied this straight from the jquery-ui site!

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra comma on line 16, between the closing brace for the "Cancel" function and the closing brace for the `buttons` object.

You've actually made the same mistake twice again on lines 36 and 56. Each time at the end of specifying the buttons for the dialogs.

IE sees this as a syntax error, where other browsers are more lenient (after all, an empty statement after a comma isn't going to have any effect).

Comment: Yeah, noticed a few minutes after I posted. Thanks for the find... could have sworn I copied this straight from the jquery-ui site! Sorry I can't provide two green check marks!